# Why is push() not working for new types in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am trying to use the push method to append a variable of type Card (declared by a type alias) to an array of Card but the push is not working.

```
enum Color {
    pique,
    carreau,
    trefle,
    coeur
}

type Card = {
    color: Color,
    value: number
}

function createCard(color: Color, value: number): Card{
    return {color, value};
}

let cardArr : Card[];
let card = createCard(Color.pique,2);
cardArr.push(card);
```

Comment: cardArr.push(card); to cardArr.push(carte); ?

Comment: Initiate your cardArr to `[]` and card is misspelled as carte

`
const cardArr : Card[] = [];
const card = createCard(Color.pique,2);
cardArr.push(card);
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable hasn't been initialized. This

```
let cardArr : Card[];
```

Is basically the same as this Javascript

```
let cardArr;
```

i.e. the variable has no value. Consider

```
let cardArr : Card[] = [];
```